# Cover cuts for knapsack constraint with integer variables

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization, knapsack, branch-and-cut, valid-inequalities

It is known for knapsack type constraint $\sum_{i \in N} a_i x_i \leq b , x \in \{0,1\}$, we can generate the so called cover cuts that have the sum of coefficient in a set C greater than b. The cover cuts are $\sum_{j \in C} x_j \leq |C| - 1, ~\forall~ C \subseteq N$.

Is it possible to generate the similar kind of cuts if x is integer, $x \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.? Or there a way to generate other kind of valid inequalities from this constraint?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the integer knapsack set as:

$$ K_{I} = \{ x \in Z^{N}_{+} : ax \leq b, x \leq u\} $$

Let $C \subseteq N$ be a cover if $\lambda = \sum_{i \in C} u_ia_i − b \gt 0$ and consider the restriction $K_I (N \text{\\} C,  \varnothing)$ obtained by fixing all $x_i, i \in N \text{\\} C$ to zero. Extending the combinatorial argument on covers for the $0$-$1$ knapsack set, since not all variables $x_i, i \in C$ can be at their upper bound simultaneously, inequality:

$$ \sum_{i \in C} x_i \leq u(C)-1 \quad (1)$$

is valid for $K_I (N \text{\\} C,  \varnothing)$. Another way to write the above inequality is:

$$ \sum_{i \in C} (u_{i} - x_{i}) \geq 1 \quad (2)$$

which states that at least one $x_{i}$ must be less than its upper bound. However, observe that if $a_i \lt \lambda$ for all $i \in C$ the left-hand side of (2) is greater than $1$ for all feasible solutions. This suggests the strengthening:

$$ \sum_{i \in C} (u_{i} - x_{i}) \geq \lceil \lambda/ \bar{a} \rceil $$

where $\bar{a} = \text{max}_{i \in C} a_{i}$. Suppose the integer knapsack is given as:

$$ K_{I}=\{ x \in \text{Z}^2: 5x_{1} + 9x_{2} \leq 45, x_{1} \leq 6, x_{2} \leq 4\}$$

Let $C = \{1,2\}$ be an integer cover with $\lambda = 30 + 36 − 45 = 21$. The following inequality:

$$ (6-x_{1}) + (4-x_{2}) \geq 1 $$

does not support $K_{I}$ . However, the strengthened inequality:

$$ (6-x_{1}) + (4-x_{2}) \geq \lceil 21/9 \rceil $$

defines a facet of $K_{I}$ for this example. For more details please, see the following paper.

Also, it seems the mentioned integer knapsack set can be supposed as a capacity constraint in the planning models that other valid inequalities like Gomory cuts, MIR cuts, etc. can be applied on.

---

*Atamtürk, A. Cover and Pack Inequalities for (Mixed) Integer Programming. Ann Oper Res 139, 21–38 (2005). https://doi.org/10.1007/s10479-005-3442-1*

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Another way of doing this is by extending the number of items. Suffices to create $\lfloor \frac{b}{a_i} \rfloor$ dummy items to each item $i \in N$. Thus, we would have the new items set $N^{'} = \bigcup_{i \in N} N_i$, where $N_i = \{ i_k : k \in \mathbb{N}^{*}_{\leqslant \lfloor \frac{b}{a_i} \rfloor} \}$ is the set of dummies items of item $i \in N$. Resulting in the following formulation.

Max $\sum_{i \in N^{'}} p_i x_i$

s.t.

$\sum_{i \in N^{'}} a_i x_i \leqslant b$

$x \in \mathbb{B}^{|N^{'}|}$

With the following cover cuts.

$\sum_{i \in C} x_i \leqslant |C| - 1 \quad\quad \forall C \subseteq N^{'} : \sum_{i \in C} a_i > b$